# TLS conneciton is droped on google compute when call is intiated from docker container

Tags: docker, ssl, google-cloud

I am using Google cloud compute with docker installed on it and I am trying to connect between 2 nodes with secured connection from the container.

When call is performed directly form HOST VM, both secured and not secured calls are working fine. When the same calls are made for the container, only not secured call succeeds. Secured call is hanging on TLS Client Hello. The request is getting to the target server and it is picking up TLS Handshake. But nothing is getting back to the docker container and eventually it timeouts.

I've tried to force tls version downgrade, use only http1.1, with no luck. Any ideas what can be the cause?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.